# Can I pass parametrized arguments to a setup function using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a folder with many pytest tests. Most of those tests require a common setup. I want to have that setup in a base class that I use to define my tests. That base class uses the hook of pytest to setup the test.

When one tests uses that class, I want to be able to provide arguments to the setup method.

Lets take as an example the following code:

```py
"""
Example module A
"""

import pytest


class BaseTestClass:
    """
    Inherit from here
    """

    def setup_method(self, method):
        """
        Pre-configure a test
        """
        print(f"\nPre-configuring test {method.__name__}")
        print("--> I want my parameter of the function here to setup the test <--")


class TestClassA(BaseTestClass):
    """
    Test module a
    """

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("parameter", ["1", "2", "3"])
    def test_a(self, parameter: str):
        """
        Test a
        """
        print(f"Running test with: {parameter=}")

class TestClassB(BaseTestClass):
    """
    Test module b
    """

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("parameter", ["a", "b", "c"])
    def test_a(self, parameter: str):
        """
        Test b
        """
        print(f"Running test with: {parameter=}")
```

Why I follow this approach? I want to have my code to setup the tests in a single place `BaseTestClass`. I would like to have it automatically done in my tests, therefore the `setup_method`.

My problem:
I can not pass my test parameters to the test. Is there another way of doing this?